# Why uncontrolled input elements lose inputs during reconciliation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

Below is the sample code that display a checkbox to wrap content, an text input field, and a counter with a button to increment

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      wrapContent: false
    }
  }

  handleAdd = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
  }

  toggleWrap = () => {
    this.setState(state => state.wrapContent = !state.wrapContent);
  }

  wrapContent(content) {
    return this.state.wrapContent ?
      <div className="bg-secondary p-2">
        <div className="bg-light">{content}</div>
      </div>
      : content;
  }

  render() {
    return this.wrapContent(
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.wrapContent} onChange={this.toggleWrap} />
        <input className="form-control"/>  {/* <--------value disappear after toggling */}
        <DisplayCounter counter={this.state.counter} />
        <div className="text-center">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleAdd}>Increment</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class DisplayCounter extends Component {

  render() {
    return <React.Fragment><div>
      <h2>{this.props.counter}</h2>
    </div></React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

If I enter some text in the input, click Add button a couple of time and then toggle the checkbox, the value of the input is gone while the value of `DisplayCounter` still persists.

What I don't understand is why the input lose its value, isn't that react use virtual dom to minimize the number of DOM updates, so if virtual dom works for `DisplayCounter`, why it doesn't work for the uncontrolled form element like input?

understand why uncontrolled input elements lose its input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input there is an `uncontrolled input`. It keeps the data in itself. When it unmounts, the data gets erased together with him. The next time it appears, it is a fresh new input.

`DisplayCounter` keeps its value, because it is a `controlled component`, you keep its value in state `this.state.counter`

Comment: I understand it keeps the data in itself, and when it unmounts, can't react use virtual dom to know that it doesn't need to make any change to the dom for the uncontrolled input?

Comment: But you are removing it from the virtual DOM. The way it works is: if the element type is new, the old one gets unmount and the new one mounts. This happens in your wrapContent. You are changing the parent node, that unmounts the current node and it gets re-created under the new parent